# trigger two different events using jquery beauty tip

Tags: jquery, beautytips

I am using jquery beauty tips plugin to generate edit/view note info on note icon. I need to show tool tip text on mouse over of icon and also on click on icon note info should open in edit mode. I am trying to trigger both event but its not working. Its working fine separately if I commented out other one.

Code to generate tooltip in edit content mode

```
$('.prompt').bt({
trigger: 'click',
positions: 'bottom',
contentSelector: "$(this).parent().find('.promptContent').html();",
});
$('.prompt').parent().find('.promptContent').css({'z-index':'9999999'});
```

Code to mouseover tooltip display

```
$('.prompt').bt({
trigger: 'hover',
positions: 'right',
cssStyles: {width: '200px' },
contentSelector: "$(this).parent().find('.promptContent1').html();",
});
$('.prompt').parent().next().find('.promptContent1').css({'z-index':'9999999'});
```

How can I trigger both events at the time to work differently?

Thanks!